# Is any option to add TICK MARK on the right side of the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

By default android have an option to enable BACK ARROW on the left of the toolbar using

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

same like i need TICK MARK on the right of the toolbar, is there any method to enable TICK MARK in android by default.

Comment: You can have a menu item with a tick icon.

Comment: @Raghunandan - Without having icon we have back icon. Like that any option is available to have Tick icon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First download the "done" icon as png from the [materials icon library](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_done)

Copy the icons to your projects drawable folder.

Then create a file in res/menu called menu_example.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_done"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then add the following code to your Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_example, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where would you add the onclick event or how?

Comment: Check out https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions. You would want to add a onOptionsItemSelected(...) to your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

To have a onClick listener for the tick you can implement this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_example, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    return true;
}
```